# How to get direct link to video?

Tags: android, flash, webview, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with playing video in my app. Basically what I want to do is getting direct link to video like: `www.embed.videotube.com/player/?id=431436[...].mp4` from: `http://embed.videotube.com/player/?id=431436`. I've seen some websites like www.videotools.12pings.net which will get proper link.

Is there any option how to cope in situation where there is no proper API ? (example: api for youtube)

After clicking on video thumb:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("www.embed.videotube.com/player/?id=431436[...].mp4"));
myContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a direct link. You could verify it by running fiddler or any HTTP traffic monitoring tool, while playing the video, the video link will be displayed in the inspector window.

Comment: But is there any chance to get direct link before playing video without using any external tools?

Comment: yes, without using fiddler, open up chorme, press F12 for the developer toolbar, navigate to the "network" tab, where you can see the streaming links.

Comment: in my app no one will lookin for an links in chrome on Android device. I need to get this link in my java code before I run specified by user video.